# Amend a commit on upstream master without force push to master

Tags: git

Let's say I `$ git log` and get something like this

```
- fix(login): can login
# I want to amend this commit msg
- bleh
- feat(login): facebook oauth
```

I can do...

```
git checkout -b fix/history
git rebase -i
# use reword to amend a non-previous commit
git push origin fix/history
```

While the diff for this PR is empty, I'm not sure if merging this would simply add two commits rather than amending `HEAD~n` commits.

Is the only way to amend via `rebase -i` to do it on master and force push?

Answer (score 3):

You can try `git-notes` [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes). This will only add some additional information to your last commit message not fully changed or modified it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to modify a commit in any way without modifying the git history.
Whenever you rebase, amend or do any modification to the history (even just messages), you create a new commit with the same/modified content.

Force pushing any branch that could be already pull-ed by other users is very dangerous as it will create git history fork.

If you work alone, or can communicate clearly to other coworkers to delete they local version of the branch and pull the new one, feel free to force push.